# How to run a perl script from another passing parameters?

Tags: perl, parameters

**How to run a perl script from another passing parameters?**

I'm trying to use a solution found in a internet post that i can't find anymore.
It was something like:

```
do 'script.cgi param1 param2';
```

And in the other script I'm using simply the shift to get those parameters:

```
#Parameters
my $param1= shift;
my $param2= shift;
```

I saw people using system with args, but is it better for real?
If not, how can I fix the solution with 'do EXPR'?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, I solved doing:

```
{local @ARGV = (@my_args); do $script;}
```

It works. If anybody has any better suggestions feel free to tell them to me.
Meantime i'm using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are two better ways I can think of:

```
system($script, @my_args);
```

and

```
my $cmd = $script . ' ' . join(' ', @my_args);
my $return = `$cmd`;
```

Both solutions pass the arguments in `@my_args`. The `system()` call returns the exit code of the executed program, while the backticks solution (``) returns the output for later parsing.

Comment: Your solution with backticks will fail if there is whitespace in any of the parameters

Comment: Can you explain please?  
My solution with do or the one with system?

Comment: I would always prefer `system()`, but YMMV.