# Perl: What is the fastest way to run a perl script from within a perl script?

Tags: perl

I am writing a Perl script that uses other Perl scripts (not mine). Some of them receive inputs with flags and some don't. Another thing that I need is to redirect the outputs of these scripts to different files. For example:

```
W\O flags: script1.pl arg1 arg2 arg3 > output1.log

W flags: script2.pl -a 1 -b 2 -c 3 > output2.log
```

Bottom line - I was using `system()` to do this, but then I found out that the script takes too long.
I tried doing this with `do()` but it didn't work (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297890/how-to-run-a-perl-script-from-another-passing-parameters)).

So what is the fastest way to achieve that?

Comment: `system` does not add measurable overhead. Could you explain better what you mean by "fastest" way?

Comment: Using `system()` doesn't slow down the external script (unless you're *really* low on memory/file-descriptors/etc) in any place that perl is already fast enough (i.e: not embedded).

Comment: Are you trying to run multiple things at the same time?

Comment: @Zaid, it doesn't require recompiling everything, so it can take a few seconds.

Comment: @user1953271, `system` and `do` aren't the same thing. You can't just swap one for the other. In fact, `do EXPR` doesn't really ever make sense. If you want to execute the second script in the same interpreter as the first, make it into a module.

Comment: What do you mean it "didn't work" with `do`?

Comment: @Zaid, I run this script for testing, so I want it to run as many times as possible. Therefore, I'm trying to optimize the code.To my understanding using [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)() creates a child process and I would like to save that time.

Comment: @ikegami, It would be pretty difficult adding the other scripts as modules since I didn't write them, and they're not used only by me. I just want to run them with as less overhead as possible.

@AKHolland, I tried doing something similar to the [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297890/how-to-run-a-perl-script-from-another-passing-parameters). The other script didn't get the flags/arguments as it expected them. Moreover, I don't know how to redirect the output using `do()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your test script define a subroutine that executes everything you want to run, then make your main script read the Perl code of the test script and invoke that subroutine - so the test script will look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# defines how to run a test

use strict;
use warnings;

sub test
{
    my ($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) = @_;
    # run the test
    (...)
)
```

The main script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# runs all of the tests

use strict;
use warnings;

require 'testdef.pl';  # the other script

foreach (...)
{
    (...)
    test($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
}
```

This is still a very basic way of doing it.
The proper way, as ikegami says, is to turn the test script into a [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_module).
That will be worthwhile if you will be creating more test script files than just these two or if you want to install the scripts in various locations.

Answer (score 0):

Use a multi argument system call: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

This is not going to execute the shell, you could spare a few CPU cycles

```
system(qw(script1.pl arg1 arg2 arg3 > output1.log));
```

> "As an optimization, may not call the command shell specified in
>   $ENV{PERL5SHELL} . system(1, @args) spawns an external process and
>   immediately returns its process designator, without waiting for it to
>   terminate. "

if you are not interested in the return status you could use exec instead or you could use fork/thread for paralel execution.

Comment: If you're worried about CPU cycles, you'll also want to avoid forking off a second `perl`.